# Running Ascii regex over non-ASCII characters with UTF-8

Tags: c++, regex, boost, utf-8

```
#include <boost/regex.hpp>

#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    std::string text = argv[1];
    std::string patterns = argv[2];

    boost::regex regex = boost::regex(patterns);

    boost::smatch match;

    std::cout << boost::regex_search(text, match, regex) << std::endl;    
}
```

If I run the program over the input `hello¿ ¿` (containing a non-ASCII character with UTF-8 encoding) it returns `0` i.e. not found, but if I run it over the input hel√ √ (again containing non-ascii) it returns 1, i.e. found.

My question: What is the expected behavior of `boost::regex` (i.e. the ascii version) when run over utf characters?

---

Edit: Thanks for all the comments, I am still interested as to why exactly 1 is output, since both the text and the regex contain non-ascii characters. My guess would be that the bytes are interpreted as ascii and thus they match.

Comment: What is your `patterns`?

Comment: @ Wiktor Stribiżew the second parameter, i.e. ¿ √ respectively

Comment: There is no such thing as a "UTF" character. If you meant "a non-ASCII character with UTF-8 encoding", you should say that.

Comment: @ rici  thanks for your remark, you are of course right and I changed the question accordingly.

Comment: And both of those print 1 on my system, which is certainly what I'd expect. (I use a UTF-8 locale so the characters should be passed through verbatim to the program.)

Comment: On my system, both print 1 too

Comment: Also on coliru, using the standard c++ library instead of boost: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3256ca7250839e7e

Comment: Thanks for all the comments, I am still interested as to why exactly 1 is output, since both the text and the regex contain non-ascii characters. My guess would be that the bytes are interpreted as ascii and thus they match...

Comment: @user695652 your guess is right. For instance, the UTF8 encoding of `√` is `E2 88 9A`, which is interpreted as `âˆš` in Latin-1. The interesting question here is why you get a `0` for `¿` since it's `C2 BF`, interpreted as `Â¿`. Can you share some details about your system, and how you invoked the command (ie how *exactly* do you pass the parameters)?

Comment: I've got 1 for both cases. Boost 1.61, Windows 10, Visual Studio 2015. But I used string constants: "hello\xC2\xBF" and "hello\xE2\x88\x9A" instead of command line arguments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Using regular expressions on ASCII strings, is about using "bytes" to find a pattern in.
   Using regular expressions on UTF-8 strings, is about using regular expressions on "multi-byte" sequences, where a sequence represents a Unicode code point.
   Thus the regular expression gets applied to a Unicode string with an encoding with variable byte-count per character.
   UTF-8 strings contain multi-byte sequences with 1 to 4 bytes, which representing a Unicode "character".
   In UTF-8 only ASCII 7 bit characters are 1 byte "wide".
   So - ***using an ASCII regular expression engine on an UTF-8 encoded string***, ignores the multi-byte sequences in the UTF-8 encoded string and causes a pattern matching byte by byte. The results of this ASCII regular expression engine usage on an UTF-8 encoded string ***is invalid***.

   Please take a look at http://utfcpp.sourceforge.net.

   To get the regular expressions working on UTF-8 encoded strings, you have to …

   - have UTF-8 string iterators usable with the regular expressions, or
   - use `std::codecvt_utf8` in combination of setting temporarily the global locale to get the regular expression working, or
   - have to convert the UTF-8 encoded string into a UTF-16 encoded string to be used with an Unicode regular expression engine - based on std::wstring.
2. The regex_search function returns a boolean and `true` on a match.
   In your case the ASCII regular expression pattern matches a part of the UTF-8 encoded string, which is parsed invalidly as ASCII string - as you assumed!
   If you have English text in an UTF-8 encoded string, then an ASCII regular expression engine can be used safely. Leaving the ASCII 7 bit range, makes the result of the ASCII regular expression engine unreliable.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bug and not a feature:
I tried your example on a better system (g++ 4.9.2 on Windows MinGW) and all happens well:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>
int main()
{ std::string text ="hello¿"; // or "hello√"
  std::string patterns ="¿";  // or "√"
  std::regex regex = std::regex(patterns);
  std::smatch match;
  std::cout << std::regex_search(text, match, regex) << std::endl;
}
```

with output:

```
1
```

Comment: Question: was your source code compiled as UTF-8 encoded source code? Since I do not see the content of "text" marked as UTF-8 (u8"...").

If so, the ASCI RE engine matches the two bytes (0xC2 0xBF) in the pattern with the "inverted question mark" BYTES in the variable "text".

If not the ASCII RE engine matches the ASCII character 0xBF in the content of the variable "text".

Both variants won't use the Unicode code point \u00BF in the content of the variable "text"!

Yes - the ASCII RE enginee claims to succeed in searching for the pattern, but not searching for the right thing!

Comment: @Martin: Yes, I use eclipse, and the source is UTF-8 encoded.